# Font Awesome not rendering in Vue built Web Component

Tags: vue.js, build, font-awesome, web-component

I have a Vue component that I'm compiling into a web component using the following build command:

```
npm run build -- --target wc --name projName src\components\server-config.vue
```

I'm missing something though in my Vue file cause the web component won't render the font awesome icons. Here is what it looks like when I, "npm run serve"

[image: Correct Looking example]

This is what it looks like after I compile it into a web component and open it in demo.html:
[image]

I see several issues:

- Fonts are different
- Missing Eye button for peeking the password
- Checkbox box is missing (though if you mouse over it you still get a glow effect)
- Eye icon is missing. (Just included as a test outside of Vuetify)

How can I properly include fonts into my component? Here is my current vue file:

```
<template>
    <div style="text-align: center; font-family: sans-serif">
      <v-text-field label="Password" class="mx-4" v-model="password" :type="showPass ? 'text' : 'password'" @click:append="showPass = !showPass" :append-icon="showPass ? 'far fa-eye' : 'far fa-eye-slash'"></v-text-field>
      <v-checkbox class="mx-4" v-model="useIntegratedAuthentication" label="Use Integrated Authentication" ></v-checkbox>
      <div>
        <i class="far fa-eye"></i>
        <span>My eye here</span>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  @import '../../node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
  @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900';
  @import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css';
</style>

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/XXXXXXXXX.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script lang="ts">
import { VTextField, VCheckbox } from 'vuetify/lib';
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify';
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  vuetify,
  components: {
    VTextField, VCheckbox
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showPass: false,
      password: '',
      useIntegratedAuthentication: false
    };
  }
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a workable solution. You need to load the font-faces inside a script tag after the component is mounted:

```
mounted() {
  const css = `
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: block;
  src: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot);
  src: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2) format("woff2"), url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff) format("woff"), url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf) format("truetype"), url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-brands-400.svg#fontawesome) format("svg")
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: block;
  src: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot);
  src: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2) format("woff2"), url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff) format("woff"), url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf) format("truetype"), url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome) format("svg")
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: block;
  src: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot);
  src: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2) format("woff2"), url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff) format("woff"), url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf) format("truetype"), url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome) format("svg")
}`;

  // if our style is already injected we do not need to inject it a second time
  if (!document.getElementById('myCustomInjectedStyle')) {
    const head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.id = 'myCustomInjectedStyle';
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerText = css;
    head.appendChild(style);
  }
},
```

I never got material designs to work for the checkbox so I updated my vuetify.ts file to always use font awesome.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'fa'
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Use font awesome globally

Add in yuor project/public/index.html head tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ref="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And use the tags from their site in your component. like `<i class="fab fa-adn"></i>`

Comment: This will not be built into the web component.